# Create Ldap search filter with join method refactor

Tags: c#, ldap, refactoring

I have string collection of login names. I create filter string for ldap search and method GetFilter. How else can refactor GetFilter method. There may be another way for create filter string?

```
List<string> logins = new List<string> {"211C69C4-D0FA-4CB5-91E5-B6B109B3F784", "311C69C4-D0FA-4CB5-91E5-B6B109B3F784"}
```

Get filter method:

```
public string GetFilter(IEnumerable<string> logins)
            {
                var result = string.Join("(loginName=", logins.Select(x => (x + ")")));
                return string.Format("(|(loginName={0})", result);
            }
```

Result filter string:

```
string filter = "(|(loginName=211C69C4-D0FA-4CB5-91E5-B6B109B3F784)(loginName=311C69C4-D0FA-4CB5-91E5-B6B109B3F784))";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create GetFilter as:

```
public string GetFilter(IEnumerable<string> logins)
{
    return string.Format("(|{0})", 
           string.Concat(logins.Select(x => string.Format("(loginName={0})", x))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm implemented a new version:

```
    public string Get(string filterName, List<string> filterValues)
    {
        var concatFilter = string.Join("", GetItems(filterName, filterValues));
        return string.Format("(|{0})", concatFilter);
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetItems(string filterName, IEnumerable<string> filterValues)
    {
        return filterValues.Select(filterValue => Get(filterName, filterValue));
    }

    public string Get(string filterName, string filterValue)
    {
        return string.Format("({0}={1})", filterName, filterValue);
    }
```